# Titanium opening Alloy controller from button click exception

Tags: java, android, exception, titanium, titanium-alloy

So this appears to work fine in iOS, but in Android when I create a controller and open it's view from a button press.

This is the code I'm calling:

```
function goToWebView(){
    win.close();
    var test = Alloy.createController('web').getView();
    test.open();
}

...

button.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    Ti.API.info("Button clicked!")
    goToWebView(); //<-- exceptions start here, only on Android
});
```

It gives these exceptions:

( clean format:  http://pastebin.com/8f6cCh1X )

> [ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [4929,5505] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.addOnLifecycleEventListener(org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLifecycle$OnLifecycleEvent)' on a null object reference; Titanium 3.4.1,2014/11/13 13:33,5982e8f
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.addOnLifecycleEventListener(org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLifecycle$OnLifecycleEvent)' on a null object reference
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.WebViewProxy.createView(WebViewProxy.java:83)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:483)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:225)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.WebViewProxy.handleMessage(WebViewProxy.java:198)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>       [ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

I get the same exception if I call goToWebView() from a timeout as well. It works in Android if I don't call it from a button event or some kind of callback, but if it's in a callback it gives those exceptions.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide view and controller of the web file you are opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your context before opening another.

```
function goToWebView(){
    win.close(); // <-- HERE
    var test = Alloy.createController('web').getView();
    test.open();
}
```

Try inverting it:

```
function goToWebView(){
    var test = Alloy.createController('web').getView();
    test.open();
    win.close();
}
```

Btw if `win` is your main window, usually you don't need to `.close` it because it has `exitOnClose` enabled.